# parse-server-example has issue

Tags: video-streaming, mp4, parse-server

Steps:
1) clone parse-server-example
2) cd into directory of parse-server-example
3) run pm install to download node_modules
4) navigate to parse-server file in node_modules folder
5) notice the file structure and click on some js files and notice the syntax
6) clone parse-server from github into a separate directory
7) go to parse-server folder and notice that all of the code is in a folder called "src" where as in the parse-server-example, parse-server dependency has a folder called "lib" with all the code. The parse-server standalone cloned project has more modern nodejs syntax as well.

I noticed this issue while debugging an issue with not being able to stream videos. I followed [this thread](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/pull/2437), and I was told that as of version 2.2.18 streaming is supported based on the code from @Bragegs. I looked at the parse-server files that nam downloaded into the parse-server-example project and his changes where not there! Can someone please explain the inconsistency with parse-server-example's parse-server and the standalone parse-server project?

Answer (score 1):

As of commit 2fe357c in parse-server-example, parse-server-example will automatically use the latest version of parse-server from npm.

https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server-example/blob/master/package.json

If you're not seeing that happen, you may not be using the latest version of parse-server-example